# Accessing a column/field from a csv file in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to access particular variable from a csv file as shown below:

Month,Year,leaves
Jan,2011, 20
Feb, 2011, 30
Mar,2011, 40

What I am trying to achieve is to create a bar chart with height being the leaves value. Below is the code that I used to access leaves field from the csv file imported. I am doing something wrong here, as I am new to D3.js I am pretty confused about accessing an object or referencing an object (syntax in general). I don't care about year, month, I am just trying to create a simple bar chart with leaves. Any help or pointer towards valuable resources would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
  <h4> D3 Bar Chart  </h4>
</head>
<style>
  .bar{
        display:inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 80px;
        margin-right: 2px;
        background-color: teal;
  }

</style>
<body>
<script>
d3.csv("sl_month_year.csv", function(error, data)
{ if(error) {
  console.log(error);}
  else {console.log(data);
  var bar = d3.selectAll("body")
                .select("div")
                .data(data.length)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class","bar")
                .style("height", function(d) { for (i=0; i <= d.length; i++) { return d.[i].leaves + "px" ;});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things that seem wrong to me in your code.
First, you try to access a property using d.[i].leaves in your loop; I think what you try to do is d[i].leaves.
Second, you do not actually need to loop on the elements in your collection, as d3 will handle that for you.
I would go for a different way of using selections, using a simple select for the body and a selectAll for the div's, and bind to the data directly instead of data.length.

Code below should be fine (untested though):

```
d3.csv("sl_month_year.csv", function(error, data){
  if(error) {
      console.log(error);}
  else {
      console.log(data);
      var bar = d3.select("body")
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","bar")
            .style("height", function(d) {         
                      return d.leaves + "px" ;
            });

});
```